# pandas flow control inside pandas syntax

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to re-format a column in my data frame so that it's ready for conversion into date.

The problem is that the raw data's values for single digit month (e.g. January) did not begin with 0. Instead, 1 is expressed as Jan. For hours and minutes, 00:05, for example, was expressed as 5. I need to add 0s to those values' initial position in order to convert them into date.

What I did is use for-loop:
e.g.:

```
for i in range(len(flight1)):
    if len(str(flight1.iloc[i,2])) == 1:
        flight1.iloc[i,24] = '0' + str(flight1.iloc[i,24])
    else:
        flight1.iloc[i,24] = str(flight1.iloc[i,24])
```

But the data is pretty large (300,000+rows) and it is very slow to use for-loop. I tried to build up new columns by

```
flight['need_cor_m'] = flight1['month'].apply(len)
```

to get the length of each value.

Is there any way to perform the for-loop function using pandas or other faster way?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post some examples of "worst-case-sceanrio" dates that you have there? I presume they are in string format too (dtype object)?

Comment: The data has separate columns of year, month, day. For hours and minutes, it's one column but all values did not begin with 0, as an example, 01:15 is 115, 00:05 is 5 in my data. Year, month, day are in int format and hours and minutes is in float...but data type is not the hardest issue here...

Comment: Month, for example May, is not 05 but 5. Day, for example 9th, is not 09 but 9.

Comment: Pandas can parse a date from 3 different fields, have a look at the `parse_dates` arg in `pandas.to_csv` documentation